# What is the .data.rel.ro used for?

Tags: gcc, objdump

I am using objdump to analyze a shared object's memory usage. Along with the .data and .rodata sections I see a **.data.rel.ro** section.

Anyone know what this used for?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I found the answer [here](http://www.airs.com/blog/archives/189):

> gcc, the GNU linker, and the glibc dynamic linker cooperate to
>   implement an idea called read-only relocations, or relro. This permits
>   the linker to designate a part of an executable or (more commonly) a
>   shared library as being read-only after dynamic relocations have been
>   applied.
>
> This may be used for read-only global variables which are initialized
>   to something which requires a relocation, such as the address of a
>   function or a different global variable. Because the global variable
>   requires a runtime initialization in the form of a dynamic relocation,
>   it can not be placed in a read-only segment. However, because it is
>   declared to be constant, and therefore may not be changed by the
>   program, the dynamic linker can mark it as read-only after the dynamic
>   relocation has been applied.